# Problems with AJAX error event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having problems with AJAX error event. I've manage to put together some code using questions/answers from this site (I'm javascript newb)

After successfully implementing *success message* on successful login and showing div element success (shown below)

```
<div class="alert alert-success"> <strong>Logging in..</strong></div>
```

I'm trying to show error message on unsuccessful login on my login modal form.
Here is the code for modal form

```
<form  id="myform" method="POST" role="form">
<div class="modal fade" id="test" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Prijava</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="error">
              <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Error, try again!</strong> </div>
            </div>
            <div id="thanks">
              <div class="alert alert-success"> <strong>Logging in..</strong></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="user">User:</label>
               <input name="user" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Unesi korisnika">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="pass">Password:</label>
               <input name="pass" type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Unesi lozinku">
            </div>   
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  id="reset" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitForm">Login in!</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
```

And here is my code for AJAX code

```
$("#error").hide();
$("#thanks").hide();
$("#myform").submit(function (e) {
    var url = "login.php";
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#thanks").show();
            setTimeout(function() {
            top.location.href ='admin.php';
        }, 2000);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#error").show();
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Success event is working fine, but the problem lies in error event. No matter what I write, it shows `#thanks` div and completely ignores `#error` div. I just want to show #thanks on successfully login and #error div on unsuccessful login in modal form.

Comment: Is `.error` handler ever invoked ?

Comment: `error` event fires when there's some error on server side - your script is unavailable or there is 40x/50x status code. Messages from your script that no user found or provided password is wrong are not __errors__.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense..what do you suggest on that matter ?

Comment: Check response `data` in `success` event callback. Pass Y/true/whatever on successful login, N/false/whatever otherwise.

Comment: What is response from `php` on unsuccessful login?

Comment: Redirects to index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send data back to the browser from the php on the server with a message for the ajax success function to process:

login.php

```
//do your stuff then
if (everything_is_OK) {echo "good to go!";} else {echo "problem";}
```

AJAX

```
success: function (data) {
           if (data==="good to go!"){$("#thanks").show();}
           if (data==="problem"){$("#error").show();}
           }
```